# How to combine the results of two simple lenses into one

Tags: haskell, lenses

Suppose I have a data type defined as below:

```
data Register = Register { _reg_h :: Word8
                         , _reg_l :: Word8
                         }
makeLenses ''Register
```

Now if I want to define a lens that focus from a `Register` to a `Word16`. This function should be some like below:

```
refer :: Lens' Register Word16
refer = do h <- reg_h
           l <- reg_l
           return $ (fromEnum h `shiftL` 8) .&. fromEnum l
```

(`Word8`, `Word16`, `shiftL`, and `.&.` are from `Data.Word` and `Data.Bits`, and I have enabled `RankNTypes` in the beginning of my source code.)

However this code simply doesn't work. I guess it might because the full `Lens` type definition has four type parameters and that would be more complex than a simple `Lens'` to act as a simple `Monad`.

So in what way can I achieve the effect described above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a lens with do notation like that. A lens needs to contain both the notion about how to get a Word16 from a Register, and how to set a Word16 back inn. Your code only says how to get a Word16 from a Register. So it should rather be written as a straight function:

```
registerToWord16 :: Register -> Word16
registerToWord16 r = (fromEnum (view reg_h r) `shiftL` 8) .&. fromEnum (view reg_l r)
```

If you just want to get a word16 from a register, you can use this function with 
`to` from [Control.Lens.Getter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html), to get a Getter you can compose with your lenses.

If you want to be able to go the other way too so that you can set a Register from a Word16, you probably want to write an `Iso`. To write an Iso you need to define a function that goes the other way:

```
word16ToRegister :: Word16 -> Register
word16ToRegister = ...
```

You can now use the `iso :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> Iso' a b` function to create your reference.

```
refer :: Iso' Register Word16
refer = iso registerToWord16 word16ToRegister
```

An Iso is higher in the [lens hierarchy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.2) than Lens, so if you compose it with a Lens you will get a Lens.

Edit:

So you clarified in the comment that you want a register to contain more fields. In that case you want a Lens. You can write it manually like András showed in his post, or you can use the `lens :: (s -> a) -> (s -> a -> s) -> Lens' s a` function to construct it from a getter and setter like this:

```
refer :: Lens' Register Word16
refer = lens get set
    where
        get :: Register -> Word16
        get = registerToWord16

        set :: Register -> Word16 -> Register
        set reg w16 = reg & reg_h .~ word16ToRegH w16
                          & reg_l .~ word16ToRegL w16

        word16ToRegH :: Word16 -> Word8

        word16ToRegL :: Word16 -> Word8
```

Comment: the register type may contains other fields to be preserved while setting the address. in which case iso does not apply then. can I define a lens in similar way?

Answer (score 3):

For an idiomatic solution using the `lens` library you should look at Reite's answer. Here I give more of a direct answer and show how to implement the lens you intended.

The definition of the `Lens` type synonym is `Lens s t a b = Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`. Making a custom lens can be achieved by implementing a function with this type (specialized to some `s t a b`).

Generally, you implement a lens by finding some value of type `a` inside the context of type `s`, applying the `a -> f b` function to it, then wrapping the rest of the context around the resulting `f b` using `fmap`. A simple example:

```
-- we'd like to focus on the first element of a pair.
-- we change the type of  the first elem from a to a'.
-- thus the type of the whole pair changes from (a, b) to (a', b)

_1 :: Lens (a, b) (a', b) a a'
_1 f (a, b) = fmap (\a' -> (a', b)) (f a)
                     |              |
                     |              ---> apply f to the focus
                     |
                     --> wrap the result back
```

We can implement the lens for `Register` analogously:

```
refer :: Lens' Register Word16
refer f (Register h l) = fmap wrap (f val) where
    val    = fromIntegral (shiftL h 8) .&. fromIntegral l
    wrap n = Register (fromIntegral $ shiftR n 8) (fromIntegral $ 0xffff .&. n)
```

Again, we apply `f` to the value we want to focus on, then wrap the result back. The definition is only complicated slightly by the need to merge and split the numbers.